# How to get an FtpWebResponse description for a given ftp exit code?

Tags: c#, mono, ftpwebrequest

I have an FTP class that I can get the response code (or description) as expected:

```
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.StatusCode;
```

Due to a bug in mono for uploading, we have coded a work around that does not use the FTPWebRequest and related classes but uses the ftp client (on linux).

In .Net/Mono the FtpWebResponse class looks up the code to get the description

```
        response.StatusDescription
```

How can I look up the description for the return code that I have from my ftp client?

Answer (score 0):

The descriptions are not looked up, they are sent by the server as part of the status message. In `mono` the `FtpWebRequest.GetResponseStatus` method breaks apart the messages received to get the description.

For a few local error conditions, the code fakes ftp status messages from hard-coded strings, such as:

```
new FtpStatus (FtpStatusCode.ServiceNotAvailable, Locale.GetText ("Invalid response from server"));
```

You should probably try to fix whatever bug you have run into instead of hacking together workarounds. That's how open source is supposed to work.